# best way to deal with dates range in python

Tags: python, performance, date, data-structures

I'm trying to work on a project where I'm having a set of blackout dates that I need to consider before kicking off some jobs. example is explained below:

I get a json set of dates for blackout like this:

```
blackout1:
      startTime: 1-1-2016
      endTime: 1-10-2016
blackout2:
      startTime: 1-5-2016
      endTime: 1-11-2016
blackout3:
      startTime: 2-2-2016
      endTime: 2-3-2016
```

as you can see some of them overlaps and some don't. I also get a list of jobs to run on specific dates as below:

```
job1:
   runDate: 1-3-2016
job2:
   runDate: 1-13-2016
```

so in my example only job2 should run because it's not scheduled on a blackout date. 
my way of looking up dates was to create two sets one for startTime and one for endTime and then I use the first date from startTime set and last date from endTime as a range for first check when I go through the jobs. if a job is out of this range then I'll schedule it to run but if it's within this range then I will check it against all the dates. I'm taking this way to enhance performance so I wont loop through all the blackout dates if the job is not within this range.
I'm not sure if this is the best way of handling this scenario and not sure if I'm using the best data structure too.

looking for more thoughts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have so many blackout dates that a simple linear pass through all of them is too slow?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops at all, since you can compare dates directly:

```
date1 = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
date2 = datetime.date(2002, 1, 1)

print(date1 < datetime.date(2001, 1, 1) < date2)
>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you break each range into separate start and end times and sort them, you can produce a single list that tells you if a time is outside of all the ranges or not. Simply traverse the list, increment a counter when you encounter a start time and decrement it when you encounter an end time. When the counter is zero, you're *not* within a range. You can either store the counter with each entry in the list, or condense the list by taking out each start/end time that leaves a count other than 0 or 1. You can use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to do a binary search of the resulting list. If you've compacted the list then there's no need to keep a count or flag, `bisect_right` will return an even number outside of a range and an odd number within a range.